# Gem build "recipe for target 'stemmer.so' failed"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cygwin, jekyll

When installing Jekyll from gem using `gem install jekyll`, I am getting the following build error. I am using Cygwin on Windows 7 and have built the `posix-spawn` gem from source prior to installing.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll-1.1.2.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-cygwin -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -ggdb -O2 -pipe   -fno-strict-aliasing   -o porter.o -c porter.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-cygwin -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -ggdb -O2 -pipe   -fno-strict-aliasing   -o porter_wrap.o -c porter_wrap.c
rm -f stemmer.so
gcc -shared -o stemmer.so porter.o porter_wrap.o -L. -L/usr/lib -L.  -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import    -lruby191  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:214: recipe for target `stemmer.so' failed
make: *** [stemmer.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/ext/gem_make.out
```

I am using `gem v2.0.7`, `ruby v1.9.3p448`, `gcc v4.8.1` and `g++ v4.8.1`

Any ideas? I have no idea when it comes to Ruby gems. I cannot find any information on this "stemmer".

Dan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the crux of this error was in the `cannot find -lcrypt`. I installed `libcrypt-devel` and the gem compiled fine after that.

I think on most native Linux distros, this lib will already be included!

Comment: On Linux, `libcrypt` is provided by glibc.  On Cygwin, it is a separate package.

Comment: Thanks Yaakov, looks like that's why hardly anybody else had the issue. Just Cygwin users. I installed the package separately and it compiled fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, Thanks, I installed :-).

Please installing 'libcrypt-devel' in cygwin